# Paturnie nella traduzione

Tags: word-meaning

Oggi stavo pensando a come tradurre in inglese la parola "paturnie", e mi sono resa conto che anche la definizione italiana è diversa dall'uso che ne faccio di solito. 
Quale sarebbe il modo corretto in italiano (o in inglese, non so se la richiesta di traduzione sia OT) di dire "non voglio farti venire le paturnie come a me"? Non voglio farti venire le mie stesse preoccupazioni? 
Mi piaceva la parola paturnia perchè ho l'impressione che sia una cosa piu intensa di "preoccupazione" ma detta mantenendo un modo scherzoso. Sul dizionario on-line pero' la definizione è umore scontroso e malinconico

Comment: Don't quote me on that, ma credo che le domande sulle traduzioni *dalla* lingua italiana siano indeed off-topic, e vadano chieste sul sito StackExchange dedicato alla lingua di destinazione (in questo caso, [english.se]).

Comment: Confermo che la richiesta di traduzione in un'altra lingua è fuori tema. Quanto al significato in italiano, basta [un buon dizionario](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/paturnie/).

Comment: Secondo me, la domanda ha qualcosa di interessante: la risposta si potrebbe usare per illustrare gli usi della parola "paturnie", vocabolo che io personalmente non conoscevo. Si dovrebbe, però, riformulare in un altro modo per non essere fuori tema.